# Instrumented test

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am trying to run a test:

```
@HiltAndroidTest
class ActionDaoTest {

@get : Rule
var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

@get : Rule
var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

@Inject
@Named("test_db")
lateinit var database: MyDatabase

private lateinit var actionDao: ActionDao

@Before
fun setup() {
    hiltRule.inject()
    actionDao = database.actionDao()
}

@After
fun teardown(){
    database.close()
}

@Test
fun insert_assetTrue() = runTest{
    val action = ActionEntity("name","description", LocalDate.now())
    actionDao.insert(action)
    val actionList= actionDao.selectAll().first()
    assertThat(actionList).contains(action)
}
```

}

I get an error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method find(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;)Lkotlinx/coroutines/internal/ThreadSafeHeapNode; in class Lkotlinx/coroutines/internal/ThreadSafeHeap; or its super classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downgraded
'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.6.4'
to
'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.6.0'
and now it works...

Answer (score 0):

The `find` method is defined in the coroutine-core module. In my case, I missed to add that module in my dependencies. As soon as I set it up like this, it worked:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4"
androidTestImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.6.4'
```